# Attach database failed for Server '{SERVER_NAME}\{INSTANCE_NAME}'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Strange, I tried to attach the database `AdventureWorks` from this site - http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/

However, I encounter the following problem while attaching `AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf`

> *Attach database failed for Server '{SERVER_NAME}{INSTANCE_NAME}'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)*
>
> *Additional Information:*
>
> *An Exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)*
>
> *Directory Lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2008R2_Log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.). (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5133)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the "AdventureWorks2008R2_Log.ldf" file.  And put it in this folder:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"

The easiest thing to do is download the "full backup" file from that site and then restore it, (instead of attaching.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the file in the location mentioned by BOB above and as well I found that when you are trying to attach the Database, it's taking another log file into the "database details" dialogue box in the attach databases menu

You need to delete the log file which pops up along with the MDF file. This log file is from another database (in case if you are having Adventureworks2014 database as well)

The attach database then runs successfully without throwing any errors